# How to get Visual Studio 'Follow link' feature work for Flask application static files

Tags: visual-studio-code, flask

So I'm building a Flask application in Visual Studio Code, and I have the following lines in my template:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='script.js') }}"> </script>
```

When I try to Follow link (Cmd+click) on the 'script.js' VS Code is throwing the following error. Any ideas to over-ride this behavior ?

[image]

Comment: the HTML document link provider is a **static** link provider, to get the URL you want it has to execute the `url_for` function, that is not static